# Package libapache2-mod-auth-mysql is not available

Tags: php, mysql, linux, linux-mint

I'm trying to install a LAMP stack on Linux Mint 16 Mate x64 but always get an error when I run this command:

```bash
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

I'm using the default source repositories. I managed to install `apache2`, `php5` and `mysql` but whenever I install the three packages it returns:

> Package libapache2-mod-auth-mysql is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'libapache2-mod-auth-mysql' has no installation candidate

Because of this I can't use the friendly URL feature.

Comment: Also here, though needlessly closed - does not discuss the why's or the workarounds: http://askubuntu.com/questions/365061/ubuntu-13-10-gives-package-libapache2-mod-auth-mysql-has-no-installation-cand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug. See [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1243076)

Answer (score 18):

According to [this thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mod-auth-mysql/+bug/1243076) the `libapache2-mod-auth-mysql` package is no longer maintained, and not needed:

> I get the impression that many people have ended up here because they want to install a LAMP stack, since some instructions somewhere state that this package should be installed to get a LAMP stack. This is incorrect. This package is only required for Apache authentication against MySQL (as opposed to doing it at the web app end, which is far more common). It appears to me that there are cargo culted instructions floating around the Internet.
>
> — [Robie Basak](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mod-auth-mysql/+bug/1243076/comments/18)

I just installed a LAMP stack without that package, and it works fine.

```bash
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql phpmyadmin
```

Comment: It's referred to here in ubuntu help, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Answer (score 1):

I also just installed the package without libapache2-mod-auth-mysql.

Seems to work just fine.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql phpmyadmin
```